# If Or Statement Always True

Tags: vba, excel

**Summary:** I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of unneccessary columns. Because new columns may be added in the future I am deleting anything that `<>` the necessary columns.

**Problem:** I have one long `If Or` statement below that I use, but it is always true. I tried putting parentheses around each statement between `Or`'s and many other variations of parentheses but none of them were correct. Under one variation of parentheses the statement was always false, but that was the only change I received.

**Code:**

```
If (Cells(4, i).Value <> "BATCH_ID" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "Indicative" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "Company Code" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "Policy Num" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "Numeric Amount" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "Legal Amount" Or Cells(4, i).Value <> "PAYMENT_AMT") Then

      ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete

End If
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try using AND? Because OR only needs 1 condition to be true/false to execute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Others have alluded to a great concept in using `And` over `Or` in this case. I will also recommend using `Select Case` In cases where there are multiple criteria as it's much easier to read, understand and edit going forward.

```
Select Case Cells(4, i).Value

    Case Is = "BATCH_ID", "Indicative", "Company Code", "Policy Num", "Numeric Amount", "Legal Amount", "PAYMENT_AMT"

    Case Else: ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete

End Select
```

Comment: this is very readable and easier to understand than my method.

Comment: in this case there was 1 problem because `Inidicative` should be spelled `Indicative` however, this was easy to pick up on. Thanks

Comment: @MikeKellogg -> Yes, at first I was typing... then I just started copy and paste :). Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

negative "or" statements often trip people up.

You actually need to use "and". Here's the logic:

if `x <> a or x <> b`, then x can be anything except a, or x can be anything except b. So if x == a, the second statement is true, and if x == b the first statement is true. With an OR, only one of the two statements needs to be true for the whole thing to be true.

If you use "and":

if `x <> a AND x <> b`, then for the first part x can be anything except a, and for the second part x can be anything except b, but... if x is a then the first part is false, and so the whole statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

Try using AND, because you only want to delete the lines if it matches nothing. Because OR only needs 1 condition to be true/false to execute.

In your case it will say NOT EQUAL TO "Batch_ID" (if it's true -> delete) etc ..

```
If (Cells(4, i).Value <> "BATCH_ID" AND Cells(4, i).Value <> "Indicative") Then
```